# WPF, MVVM design lengthy binding consideration

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, binding

I am currently writing a WPF application, using a MVVM approach and Entity Framework.

In my MainVindow.xaml, I have a navigation system on the left. 
For each  of its navigation items, there is a corresponding user control. 
Clicking on one of its items displays the user control on the right of the main window.

I have a view model for each user control.
I bind my MainWindow.xaml to an instance of my MainViewModel class.

Each user control is binded to an instance of its corresponding viewmodel which is stored in my MainViewModel class.

In the constructor of each of these user controls viewmodels, I pass the MainViewModel.

The idea is to share an entity amongst all these viewmodels:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public SharedEntity MySharedEntity
    {
        get
        {
            return _mySharedEntity;
        }
        set
        {
            InpcLogic(_mySharedEntity);
        }
    }

    public FirstUserControlViewModel MyFirstUserControlViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myFirstUserControlViewModel == null)
                _myFirstUserControlViewModel = new FirstUserControlViewModel(this);
            return _myFirstUserControlViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, in  the FirstUserControlViewModel instance, I can access MySharedEntity this way:

```
class FirstUserControlViewModel
{
    MainViewModel _mainViewModel;

    public MainViewModel MyMainViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _mainViewModel;
        }
    }

    public SharedEntity MyMainViewmodelSharedEntity
    {
        get
        {
            return _mainViewModel.MySharedEntity;
        }
    }

    public FirstUserControlViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        _mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
    }
}
```

In my user control xaml (which is binded to the view model above), I can bind controls to this shared entity from my mainViewModel.

Now, here is my problem: When I change the shared entity from anywhere in the application, the bindings are not always refreshed on the user control level. Could it be due due to the fact that the INPC logic is in the main view model and not the user control view model?

Let's say I bind a textblock in my first user control like so:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyMainViewModel.MySharedEntity.AnyStringMember,
Mode=TwoWay,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

It works fine.

However, if I do the following

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyMainViewmodelSharedEntity.AnyStringMember,
Mode=TwoWay,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Then, bindings do not refresh when I change the shared entity. It uses the same reference to my entity in both cases, doesn't it?

**

### UPDATE

**

Here's what I'll end up doing:

In my MainViewModel, I have the following property:

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    EntityFrameworkClass _myPrivateEfObject;
    EntityFrameworkNavigationPropertyClass _myPrivateEfNavigationPropertyObject;


    public EntityFrameworkClass MyPublicEfObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _myPrivateEfObject;
        }
        set
        {
            InpcLogic(ref _myPrivateEfObject, value);
            MyPublicEfNavigationPropertyObject = _myPrivateEfObject.EntityFrameworkNavigationPropertyClass.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public EntityFrameworkNavigationPropertyClass MyPublicEfNavigationPropertyObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _myPrivateEfNavigationPropertyObject;
        }
        set
        {
            InpcLogic(ref _myPrivateEfNavigationPropertyObject, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my user control xaml, I simply use MainViewModel.MyPublicEfNavigationPropertyObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am binding my textbox to a property which does not implement any INPC behavior. Yes, it refers to the same object, but if there is no INPC behavior implemented, the graphical component can't be notified that it needs to refresh.

I am going to bind to properties within my MainViewModel and implement INPC in there.

Comment: As III mentioned: your MainViewModel seems to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` while your `FirstUserControlViewModel` doesnt. Your first binding path refers to a property on MainViewModel, the second to a property of FirstUserControlViewModel, so it's not the same object. If you do not need update notifications in your sub viewmodels, than you shouldn't implement it there and stuck to your first version of data binding.

Comment: @AndreasH.Thanks for the reply. Both the view models implement INPC. The bindings refer to different properties but the object returned but both properties is the exact same (debugging, if I change one member of the instance returned by the first property, this change is reflected in the instance returned by the second property). My problem here is not that my second VM does not implement INPC, it is rather (I think) the the getter does not have a set which calls the INPC logic.

Comment: @AndreasH. Please take a look at the two examples of binding, it shows a binding to the two properties of FirstuserControlViewModel. First case it works, second it does not work, even though it is the same object. Again, I believe it is due to the fact that my second property (MyMainViewmodelSharedEntity) does not have a set which calls the INPC logic. Don't you agree?

Comment: Of course. Do you need `MyMainViewmodelSharedEntity` at all in your user viewmodel?  If you expose `MyMainViewModel` anyway and the binding works, where's the need for an extra property,  that would require additional update logic?

Comment: @AndreasH. I don't need to. It's just easier on the eye to me: the thing is my shared object is an EntityFramework entity and I need to access its navigation properties. So I will have long binding members in my xaml...not the end of the world though. The difficulty is also that I need to access the shared object's navigation properties, which I can't do from xaml code, so I have to declare other properties which return the shared object's navigation property I want to access. Please read the update if you want to see what I'll end up doing. If you have any better idea, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the method that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In your case, you want it implemented to your `MySharedEntity` then on the setter of the `AnyStringMember` you want to `RaisePropertyChanged`.